# How to stub backbone models constructor?

Tags: backbone.js, qunit, sinon

Lets say I have a custom backbone model.

```
var model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(parameters) {
        var object = {
            key: parameters.key
        };
        this.callMethod();
        this.collection = new Backbone.Collection();
    },

    callMethod: function() {
        //code I want to test
    }
});
```

How to test new instance of this model without setuping all this object or any other stuff which is irrelevant to the test using QUnit and Sinon? Should I somehow stub this initialize method before initializing model? What is the right way to do it using these two libraries?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that your title is a bit off, you're not trying to stub the constructor but the initialize. Those are two [different](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor) things. And yes, you should stub it before initializing a new model, a stub is not a time machine :) As for Sinon I haven't used it much but looks easy enough: http://sinonjs.org/docs/#stubs

Comment: Call me dumb but I just dont understand the thing how can you stub a method of an object which is not yet created? Basic stubbing looks like this stub = sinon.stub(object, 'methodName'). I couldnt find an example with stubbing before initialize.

Comment: Oh right, that's a good point, I didn't consider that implication as I was busy confusing constructor/initialize. I would try to stub it on the prototype (ie try to stub `model.prototype.initialize` before doing `new model()`)

Comment: Prototype stubbing works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Once you don't have the model instance, you can stub the Model.prototype.

Example:

```
spyOn(Model.prototype, "initialize");
var modelInstance = new Model();
expect(Model.prototype.initialize).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comments indicated, it appears the OP was really looking for an `initialize` stub, not a `constructor` stub, and that's actually pretty easy to do:

```
sinon.stub(YourModel.prototype, 'initialize');
```

But to answer the question in the subject line, for anyone else reading this ... stubbing a constructor is a bit trickier, because the constructor is basically the class itself (ie. `YourModel` is the constructor function of `YourModel` class).  That matters because Sinon only knows how stub functions that are *properties* of something (eg. `initialize` is a property of `YourModel.prototype`).  In other words, Sinon can only stub *methods*, and the `constructor` isn't a method.

The solution to this is to look at the code you're trying to test, and see how it gets the constructor before it uses it.  For instance, let's say you want to test that `FakeView` instantiates `YourModel` in a `foo` method:

```
var FakeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    foo: function() { return new YourModel(); }
});
```

When written like that `YourModel` can't be stubbed.  But if you change it slightly, so that `YourModel` *is* a property:

```
var FakeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    foo: function() { return new this.constructor.modelClass(); }
}, {
    modelClass: YourModel
});
```

Then suddenly you can stub it:

```
var stub = sandbox.stub(FakeView, 'modelClass');
new FakeView().foo(); // stub.calledWithNew() === true
```

Hope that helps anyone else struggling with this.